# Does PowerShell Substiture -eq for -contains When Comparing a String and an Array

Tags: powershell

While comparing a string to an array in PowerShell today I mistakenly used -eq rather than -contains, but still got the expected result.

Example Code:

```
$arr = "Fred","Bob"
if($arr -eq "Bob")
    {
    Return $true
    }
    Else
    {
    Return $false
    }
```

i.e. The output from the above will be $true, as would comparing the string "Fred", but comparing with "Steve" will result in $false.  The same would happen if I used -contains.

It would appear that PowerShell has "helped me out", and turned my -eq into a -contains.  Is this assumption correct?

Secondly, is there a reason why PowerShell does this where as other languages (to my knowledge) don't?

Cheers,

Pete

P.S. Similarly, if I use -contains to compare a string to another string, it will only return $true if the two string match completely.

Comment: [When the input to an operator is a scalar value, comparison operators return a Boolean value. When the input is a collection of values, the comparison operators return any matching values.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators)

Answer (score 6):

Look at this code.

```
$arr = "Fred", "Bob"
$arr -eq "Bob"   # Bob
```

The relevant part of [the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators) is

> When the input to an operator is a scalar value, comparison operators return a Boolean value. When the input is a collection of values, the comparison operators return any matching values.

In this case, the input is a collection of values. If we turn that earlier expression around, though, so that the input (left-hand side) is the scalar value 'Bob', we get something completely different.

```
'Bob' -eq $arr   # False
```

Comment: I think it's also important to mention that the `if` conditional will return `$true` when not empty, null, or false. So `if ("Bob") {$true} else {$false}` returns `$true` and `if ('') {$true} else {$false}` returns `$false`. And it's the combination of behavior of the `-eq` comparison operator and the `if` statement that causes what the asker is seeing.

Comment: Thanks @mike-sherrill-cat-recall (and @PetSerAl)...I googled everything I could think of, but forgot to RTFM :-)

Comment: And thanks @BenH for the clarification, I now understand why the matching value "Bob" returns $true.  I am now one happy, and slightly less confused, chap :-)